# reset_default_code() not a module in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

The `reset_default_graph()` function does not show up in the module.  I've tried importing with all of tensorflow as tf and manually importing with:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

in trying:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

I get the error message:

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'